# Validating text after <br> in Atata

Tags: atata

I have this table cell on my page:

```
<td>
<strong>Some Text</strong>
<br>random description
</td>
```

I'd like to come up with a way to validate the text after the br and have it return that as `Text<T>` so I can use the atata asserts (like Should.Equal("random description")) - separately from the text inside the `<strong>` but so far have been unable to do anything more than get that text as a string by getting the td via xpath and .Split("\r\n") it's Value - is there a way to get just this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by adding  `[ContentSource(ContentSource.LastChildTextNode)]` attribute to your text control.

Alternatively, you can invoke `TextControl.GetContent(ContentSource.LastChildTextNode)` method.

Comment: Thank you, Yevgeniy - this was extremely helpful.